# Storing and retrieving non english data in to sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, utf-8

I want to store and retrieve non english  data into sqlite database.I don't know how to store my language in to db.I have read some info in forums they provide information about UTF-8 and UTF-16 ,yet i am not clear in how to stor my data into db .
hope someone will help me out here 
Thanks in advance .
any suggestion is acceptable .

Comment: Have you had trouble with `UTF-8` or do you not know how to set up a db?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite uses UTF-8 internally, and the Android libraries automatically convert between UTF-8 and the encoding used by Java strings.

There is nothing special about non-English data; anything in a Java string will be stored correctly.

Comment: so its similar like we insert regular data in to sqlite db or any extra change i have to done in code ? @CL

Comment: thnx for guide to me @CL